# Magento: get customer name when event newsletter_subscriber_save_before happens

Tags: magento

I'm using an observer for the newsletter_subscriber_save_before event which is also triggered when a customer signup with newsletter checkbox checked.

If a customer subscribed, how can I get his name?

I tried:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber()->getName()
```

but it's always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I found was:

```
$name = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('firstname') .' '. Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('lastname');
```

Maybe there are better ways but I will leave this solution as the answer for now.